# Sum items in a list with ints and strings in python

Tags: python

new to python here. I am trying to learn how to perform operations on a list that has mixed types:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
```

If the item is a str, I want to add it to output_str, and if it is an int I want to sum it. This is what I have tried:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]

for x in mylist:
    output_str = ''
    if isinstance(x, str):
        output_str += x
        print(output_str)
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        print(sum(x))
```

My expected output:

```
'jacksnaketumbleweed'
68
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-404-926417194c69> in <module>()
      5         output_str += x
      6     elif isinstance(x, int):
----> 7         print(sum(x))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I do not understand why this is happening.
Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What does it mean to sum a single number? A sum is the addition of multiple numbers.

Comment: I edited the post and added my expected output.

Comment: `sum` requires an iterable, you passed an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` function is intended to sum all the elements in an array, which explains the error you're getting. Also, if you keep `output_str` being declared inside your `for` function, everytime if scans a new value from your list, `output_str` would reset. That's why I am now declaring it only once, before the `for` even starts.

I also added the variable `final`, which will be responsible to store the sum of all numbers so far. So what we have is:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
final = 0
output_str = ''

for x in mylist:

    if isinstance(x, str):
        #here, we will concatenate each x value with the current value of output_str
        output_str += x

    elif isinstance(x, int):
        #and here, everytime x is a number, we will sum it to final's current value. This operation is equal to final = final + 1
        final += x

print(output_str)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension which is faster and more readable and simpler:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]

int_sum = sum([i for i in mylist if isinstance(i, int)])
str_join = ' '.join([i for i in mylist if isinstance(i, str)])

print(str_join)
print(int_sum)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
jack snake tumbleweed
68
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]

total = 0
output_str = ''
for x in mylist:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        output_str = output_str + x
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        total += x
print(output_str)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do sum on single element, sum requires iterable input type. You can do that like this:

Code:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]

output_str = ''
sum_of_int = 0

for x in mylist:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        output_str += x
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        sum_of_int += x

print(output_str)
print(sum_of_int)
```

Output:

```
jacksnaketumbleweed
68
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
output_str = ''
sum = 0

for i in mylist:
    if type(i) == str:
        output_str += i   
    elif type(i) == int:
        sum += i
```

Now `sum` will contain the sum of integers in your list, and `output_str` will contain the concatenation of all of the strings in your list.

Answer (score 1):

The [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function expects an iterable. Try this:

```
from functools import reduce

mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
n, s = reduce(lambda a, x: (a[0] + x, a[1]) if isinstance(x, int) else (a[0], a[1] + x), mylist, (0, ''))
print('n = {}; s = {};'.format(n, s))
```

**Output:**

```
n = 68; s = jacksnaketumbleweed;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
my_list = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
a, b = sum(e for e in my_list if isinstance(e, int)), ''.join(s for s in my_list if isinstance(s, str))
print(a, b)
```

**Output**

```
68 jacksnaketumbleweed
```

In case the list includes both float and integers you could use [Number](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number):

```
from numbers import Number

my_list = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39.0]
a, b = sum(e for e in my_list if isinstance(e, Number)), ''.join(s for s in my_list if isinstance(s, str))
print(a, b)
```

**Output**

```
68.0 jacksnaketumbleweed
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
mylist = ['jack', 12, 'snake', 17, 'tumbleweed', 39]
ints = [str(i).isnumeric() for i in mylist]
ix_int = np.flatnonzero(ints)
np.array(mylist)[ix_int].astype(int).sum()
68
```

And for the strings:

```
ix_str = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(mylist)), indices)
''.join(np.array(mylist)[ix_str])
'jacksnaketumbleweed'
```